# Assembly x86 - problems with code

Tags: assembly, x86, project, tasm

I have my project due to tomorrow and I finished it but I still have some bugs which I can't seem to understand how to fix them. I have been sitting for a long time and I just don't know what to do. I will explain the code after.

*Note - This post is really long but I really need help. If anyone is really willing to help me, I have Skype.

I will upload about half of my code because the other half 100% works:

```
proc CheckIfPlayer1Won
    Row1:
    cmp [FirstColumnArray], 1
    je Continue1Row1
    jmp Row2    
    Continue1Row1:
    cmp [SecondColumnArray], 1
    je Continue2Row1
    jmp Row2    
    Continue2Row1:
    cmp [ThirdColumnArray], 1
    je Continue3Row1
    jmp Row2
    Continue3Row1:
    cmp [FourthColumnArray], 1
    je Player1WinnerAnnounce1
    jmp Row2

    Row2:
    cmp [FirstColumnArray + 1], 1
    je Continue1Row2
    jmp Row3
    Continue1Row2:
    cmp [SecondColumnArray + 1], 1
    je Continue2Row2
    jmp Row3
    Continue2Row2:
    cmp [ThirdColumnArray + 1], 1
    je Continue3Row2
    jmp Row3
    Continue3Row2:
    cmp [FourthColumnArray + 1], 1
    je Player1WinnerAnnounce1
    jmp Row3

    Row3:
    cmp [FirstColumnArray + 2], 1
    je Continue1Row3
    jmp Row4
    Continue1Row3:
    cmp [SecondColumnArray + 2], 1
    je Continue2Row2
    jmp Row4
    Continue2Row3:
    cmp [ThirdColumnArray + 2], 1
    je Continue3Row2
    jmp Row4
    Continue3Row3:
    cmp [FourthColumnArray + 2], 1
    je Player1WinnerAnnounce1
    jmp Row4

    Row4:
    cmp [FirstColumnArray + 3], 1
    je Continue1Row4
    jmp Column1
    Continue1Row4:
    cmp [SecondColumnArray + 3], 1
    je Continue2Row4
    jmp Column1
    Continue2Row4:
    cmp [ThirdColumnArray + 3], 1
    je Continue3Row4
    jmp Column1
    Continue3Row4:
    cmp [FourthColumnArray + 3], 1
    je Player1WinnerAnnounce1
    jmp Column1

    Player1WinnerAnnounce1:
    mov dl, 22
    mov dh, 12
    mov ah, 2
    mov bh, 0
    int 10h
    lea dx, [Player1Winner]
    mov dx, offset Player1Winner
    mov ah, 9
    int 21h 
    jmp exit

    Column1:
    cmp [FirstColumnArray], 1
    je Continue1Column1
    jmp Column2
    Continue1Column1:
    cmp [FirstColumnArray + 1], 1
    je Continue2Column1
    jmp Column2
    Continue2Column1:
    cmp [FirstColumnArray + 2], 1
    je Continue3Column1
    jmp Column2
    Continue3Column1:
    cmp [FirstColumnArray + 3], 1
    je Player1WinnerAnnounce2
    jmp Column2

    Column2:    
    cmp [SecondColumnArray], 1
    je Continue1Column2
    jmp Column3
    Continue1Column2:
    cmp [SecondColumnArray + 1], 1
    je Continue2Column2
    jmp Column3
    Continue2Column2:
    cmp [SecondColumnArray + 2], 1
    je Continue3Column2
    jmp Column3
    Continue3Column2:
    cmp [SecondColumnArray + 3], 1
    je Player1WinnerAnnounce2
    jmp Column3

    Column3:
    cmp [ThirdColumnArray], 1
    je Continue1Column3
    jmp Column4
    Continue1Column3:
    cmp [ThirdColumnArray + 1], 1
    je Continue2Column3
    jmp Column4
    Continue2Column3:
    cmp [ThirdColumnArray + 2], 1
    je Continue3Column3
    jmp Column4
    Continue3Column3:
    cmp [ThirdColumnArray + 3], 1
    je Player1WinnerAnnounce2
    jmp Column4

    Column4:
    cmp [FourthColumnArray], 1
    je Continue1Column4
    jmp DiagnolLine1
    Continue1Column4:
    cmp [FourthColumnArray + 1], 1
    je Continue2Column4
    jmp DiagnolLine1
    Continue2Column4:
    cmp [FourthColumnArray + 2], 1
    je Continue3Column4
    jmp DiagnolLine1
    Continue3Column4:
    cmp [FourthColumnArray + 3], 1
    je Player1WinnerAnnounce2
    jmp DiagnolLine1

    Player1WinnerAnnounce2:
    mov dl, 22
    mov dh, 12
    mov ah, 2
    mov bh, 0
    int 10h
    lea dx, [Player1Winner]
    mov dx, offset Player1Winner
    mov ah, 9
    int 21h 
    jmp exit    

    DiagnolLine1:
    cmp [FirstColumnArray], 1
    je Continue1DiagnolLine1
    jmp DiagnolLine2
    Continue1DiagnolLine1:
    cmp [SecondColumnArray + 1], 1
    je Continue2DiagnolLine1
    jmp DiagnolLine2
    Continue2DiagnolLine1:
    cmp [ThirdColumnArray + 2], 1
    je Continue3DiagnolLine1
    jmp DiagnolLine2
    Continue3DiagnolLine1:
    cmp [FourthColumnArray + 3], 1
    je Player1WinnerAnnounce3
    jmp DiagnolLine2

    DiagnolLine2:
    cmp [FourthColumnArray], 1
    je Continue1DiagnolLine2
    jmp CheckPlayer1Number
    Continue1DiagnolLine2:
    cmp [ThirdColumnArray + 1], 1
    je Continue2DiagnolLine2
    jmp CheckPlayer1Number
    Continue2DiagnolLine2:
    cmp [SecondColumnArray + 2], 1
    je Continue3DiagnolLine2
    jmp CheckPlayer1Number
    Continue3DiagnolLine2:
    cmp [FirstColumnArray + 3], 1
    je Player1WinnerAnnounce3
    jmp CheckIfPlayer2Won   

    Player1WinnerAnnounce3:
    mov dl, 22
    mov dh, 12
    mov ah, 2
    mov bh, 0
    int 10h
    lea dx, [Player1Winner]
    mov dx, offset Player1Winner
    mov ah, 9
    int 21h 
    jmp exit

    ret
endp CheckIfPlayer1Won

proc CheckIfPlayer2Won
    Row1T:
    cmp [FirstColumnArray], 2
    je Continue1Row1T
    jmp Row2T
    Continue1Row1T:
    cmp [SecondColumnArray], 2
    je Continue2Row1T
    jmp Row2T
    Continue2Row1T:
    cmp [ThirdColumnArray], 2
    je Continue3Row1T
    jmp Row2T
    Continue3Row1T:
    cmp [FourthColumnArray], 2
    je Player2WinnerAnnounce1
    jmp Row2T

    Row2T:
    cmp [FirstColumnArray + 1], 2
    je Continue1Row2T
    jmp Row3T
    Continue1Row2T:
    cmp [SecondColumnArray + 1], 2
    je Continue2Row2T
    jmp Row3T
    Continue2Row2T:
    cmp [ThirdColumnArray + 1], 2
    je Continue3Row2T
    jmp Row3T
    Continue3Row2T:
    cmp [FourthColumnArray + 1], 2
    je Player2WinnerAnnounce1
    jmp Row3T

    Row3T:
    cmp [FirstColumnArray + 2], 2
    je Continue1Row3T
    jmp Row4T
    Continue1Row3T:
    cmp [SecondColumnArray + 2], 2
    je Continue2Row3T
    jmp Row4T
    Continue2Row3T:
    cmp [ThirdColumnArray + 2], 2
    je Continue3Row3T
    jmp Row4T
    Continue3Row3T:
    cmp [FourthColumnArray + 2], 2
    je Player2WinnerAnnounce1
    jmp Row4T

    Row4T:
    cmp [FirstColumnArray + 3], 2
    je Continue1Row4T
    jmp Column1T
    Continue1Row4T:
    cmp [SecondColumnArray + 3], 2
    je Continue2Row4T
    jmp Column1T
    Continue2Row4T:
    cmp [ThirdColumnArray + 3], 2
    je Continue3Row4T
    jmp Column1T
    Continue3Row4T:
    cmp [FourthColumnArray + 3], 2
    je Player2WinnerAnnounce1
    jmp Column1T

    Player2WinnerAnnounce1:
    mov dl, 22
    mov dh, 12
    mov ah, 2
    mov bh, 0
    int 10h
    lea dx, [Player2Winner]
    mov dx, offset Player2Winner
    mov ah, 9
    int 21h 
    jmp exit

    Column1T:
    cmp [FirstColumnArray], 2
    je Continue1Column1T
    jmp Column2T
    Continue1Column1T:
    cmp [FirstColumnArray + 1], 2
    je Continue2Column1T
    jmp Column2T
    Continue2Column1T:
    cmp [FirstColumnArray + 2], 2
    je Continue3Column1T
    jmp Column2T
    Continue3Column1T:
    cmp [FirstColumnArray + 3], 2
    je Player2WinnerAnnounce2
    jmp Column2T

    Column2T:
    cmp [SecondColumnArray], 2
    je Continue1Column2T
    jmp Column3T
    Continue1Column2T:
    cmp [SecondColumnArray + 1], 2
    je Continue2Column2T
    jmp Column3T
    Continue2Column2T:
    cmp [SecondColumnArray + 2], 2
    je Continue3Column2T
    jmp Column3T
    Continue3Column2T:
    cmp [SecondColumnArray + 3], 2
    je Player2WinnerAnnounce2
    jmp Column3T

    Column3T:
    cmp [ThirdColumnArray], 2
    je Continue1Column3T
    jmp Column4T
    Continue1Column3T:
    cmp [ThirdColumnArray + 1], 2
    je Continue2Column3T
    jmp Column4T
    Continue2Column3T:
    cmp [ThirdColumnArray + 2], 2
    je Continue3Column3T
    jmp Column4T
    Continue3Column3T:
    cmp [ThirdColumnArray + 3], 2
    je Player2WinnerAnnounce2
    jmp Column4T

    Column4T:
    cmp [FourthColumnArray], 2
    je Continue1Column4T
    jmp DiagnolLine1T
    Continue1Column4T:
    cmp [FourthColumnArray + 1], 2
    je Continue2Column4T
    jmp DiagnolLine1T
    Continue2Column4T:
    cmp [FourthColumnArray + 2], 2
    je Continue3Column4T
    jmp DiagnolLine1T
    Continue3Column4T:
    cmp [FourthColumnArray + 3], 2
    je Player2WinnerAnnounce2
    jmp DiagnolLine1T

    Player2WinnerAnnounce2:
    mov dl, 22
    mov dh, 12
    mov ah, 2
    mov bh, 0
    int 10h
    lea dx, [Player2Winner]
    mov dx, offset Player2Winner
    mov ah, 9
    int 21h 
    jmp exit

    DiagnolLine1T:
    cmp [FirstColumnArray], 2
    je Continue1DiagnolLine1T
    jmp DiagnolLine2T
    Continue1DiagnolLine1T:
    cmp [SecondColumnArray + 1], 2
    je Continue2DiagnolLine1T
    jmp DiagnolLine2T
    Continue2DiagnolLine1T:
    cmp [ThirdColumnArray + 2], 2
    je Continue3DiagnolLine1T
    jmp DiagnolLine2T
    Continue3DiagnolLine1T:
    cmp [FourthColumnArray + 3], 2
    je Player2WinnerAnnounce3
    jmp DiagnolLine2T

    DiagnolLine2T:
    cmp [FourthColumnArray], 2
    je Continue1DiagnolLine2T
    jmp CheckPlayer1Number
    Continue1DiagnolLine2T:
    cmp [ThirdColumnArray + 1], 2
    je Continue2DiagnolLine2T
    jmp CheckPlayer1Number
    Continue2DiagnolLine2T:
    cmp [SecondColumnArray + 2], 2
    je Continue3DiagnolLine2T
    jmp CheckPlayer1Number
    Continue3DiagnolLine2T:
    cmp [FirstColumnArray + 3], 2
    je Player2WinnerAnnounce3
    jmp CheckPlayer1Number

    Player2WinnerAnnounce3:
    mov dl, 22
    mov dh, 12
    mov ah, 2
    mov bh, 0
    int 10h
    lea dx, [Player2Winner]
    mov dx, offset Player2Winner
    mov ah, 9
    int 21h 
    jmp exit

    ret
endp CheckIfPlayer2Won

proc CheckPlayer1Number
    mov ah, 7
    int 21h
    cmp al, 31h
    je CheckColumn1
    cmp al, 32h
    je CheckColumn2
    cmp al, 33h
    je MoveToCheckColumn3
    cmp al, 34h
    je MoveToCheckColumn4
    jmp CheckPlayer1Number
endp CheckPlayer1Number

proc CheckColumn1
    cmp [FirstColumnArray], 0
    je ChangeColumn1Number1 
    cmp [FirstColumnArray + 1], 0
    je ChangeColumn1Number2 
    cmp [FirstColumnArray + 2], 0
    je ChangeColumn1Number3 
    cmp [FirstColumnArray + 3], 0
    je ChangeColumn1Number4
    jmp CheckPlayer1Number
endp CheckColumn1

proc ChangeColumn1Number1
    inc [FirstColumnArray]
    mov [Player1Drawx], 25h
    mov [Player1Drawy], 85h
    jmp DrawPlayer1Disc
endp ChangeColumn1Number1

proc ChangeColumn1Number2
    inc [FirstColumnArray + 1]
    mov [Player1Drawx], 25h
    mov [Player1Drawy], 67h
    jmp DrawPlayer1Disc
endp ChangeColumn1Number2

proc ChangeColumn1Number3
    inc [FirstColumnArray + 2]
    mov [Player1Drawx], 25h
    mov [Player1Drawy], 47h
    jmp DrawPlayer1Disc
endp ChangeColumn1Number3

proc ChangeColumn1Number4
    inc [FirstColumnArray + 3]
    mov [Player1Drawx], 25h
    mov [Player1Drawy], 27h
    jmp DrawPlayer1Disc
endp ChangeColumn1Number4

proc MoveToCheckColumn3
    jmp CheckColumn3
endp MoveToCheckColumn3

proc MoveToCheckColumn4
    jmp CheckColumn4
endp MoveToCheckColumn4

proc CheckColumn2
    cmp [SecondColumnArray], 0
    je ChangeColumn2Number1 
    cmp [SecondColumnArray + 1], 0
    je ChangeColumn2Number2 
    cmp [SecondColumnArray + 2], 0
    je ChangeColumn2Number3 
    cmp [SecondColumnArray + 3], 0
    je ChangeColumn2Number4
    jmp CheckPlayer1Number
endp CheckColumn2

proc ChangeColumn2Number1
    inc [SecondColumnArray]
    mov [Player1Drawx], 45h
    mov [Player1Drawy], 85h
    jmp DrawPlayer1Disc
endp ChangeColumn2Number1

proc ChangeColumn2Number2
    inc [SecondColumnArray + 1]
    mov [Player1Drawx], 45h
    mov [Player1Drawy], 67h
    jmp DrawPlayer1Disc
endp ChangeColumn2Number2

proc ChangeColumn2Number3
    inc [SecondColumnArray + 2]
    mov [Player1Drawx], 45h
    mov [Player1Drawy], 47h
    jmp DrawPlayer1Disc
endp ChangeColumn2Number3

proc ChangeColumn2Number4
    inc [SecondColumnArray + 3]
    mov [Player1Drawx], 45h
    mov [Player1Drawy], 27h
    jmp DrawPlayer1Disc
endp ChangeColumn2Number4

proc CheckColumn3
    cmp [ThirdColumnArray], 0
    je ChangeColumn3Number1 
    cmp [ThirdColumnArray + 1], 0
    je ChangeColumn3Number2 
    cmp [ThirdColumnArray + 2], 0
    je ChangeColumn3Number3 
    cmp [ThirdColumnArray + 3], 0
    je ChangeColumn3Number4
    jmp CheckPlayer1Number
endp CheckColumn3

proc ChangeColumn3Number1
    inc [ThirdColumnArray]
    mov [Player1Drawx], 65h
    mov [Player1Drawy], 85h
    jmp DrawPlayer1Disc
endp ChangeColumn3Number1

proc ChangeColumn3Number2
    inc [ThirdColumnArray + 1]
    mov [Player1Drawx], 65h
    mov [Player1Drawy], 67h
    jmp DrawPlayer1Disc
endp ChangeColumn3Number2

proc ChangeColumn3Number3
    inc [ThirdColumnArray + 2]
    mov [Player1Drawx], 65h
    mov [Player1Drawy], 47h
    jmp DrawPlayer1Disc
endp ChangeColumn3Number3

proc ChangeColumn3Number4
    inc [ThirdColumnArray + 3]
    mov [Player1Drawx], 65h
    mov [Player1Drawy], 27h
    jmp DrawPlayer1Disc
endp ChangeColumn3Number4

proc CheckColumn4
    cmp [FourthColumnArray], 0
    je ChangeColumn4Number1 
    cmp [FourthColumnArray + 1], 0
    je ChangeColumn4Number2 
    cmp [FourthColumnArray + 2], 0
    je ChangeColumn4Number3 
    cmp [FourthColumnArray + 3], 0
    je ChangeColumn4Number4
    jmp CheckPlayer1Number
endp CheckColumn4

proc ChangeColumn4Number1
    inc [FourthColumnArray]
    mov [Player1Drawx], 85h
    mov [Player1Drawy], 85h
    jmp DrawPlayer1Disc
endp ChangeColumn4Number1

proc ChangeColumn4Number2
    inc [FourthColumnArray + 1]
    mov [Player1Drawx], 85h
    mov [Player1Drawy], 67h
    jmp DrawPlayer1Disc
endp ChangeColumn4Number2

proc ChangeColumn4Number3
    inc [FourthColumnArray + 2]
    mov [Player1Drawx], 85h
    mov [Player1Drawy], 47h
    jmp DrawPlayer1Disc
endp ChangeColumn4Number3

proc ChangeColumn4Number4
    inc [FourthColumnArray + 3]
    mov [Player1Drawx], 85h
    mov [Player1Drawy], 27h
    jmp DrawPlayer1Disc
endp ChangeColumn4Number4

DrawPlayer1Loop:
    mov bh,0h
    mov cx,[Player1Drawx]
    mov dx,[Player1Drawy]
    mov al,[player1disccolor]
    mov ah,0ch
    int 10h
    add [Player1Drawx], 1h
    cmp cx, [Player1Drawx + 14h]
    jl DrawPlayer1Loop

DrawPlayer1Disc: 
    mov bh, 0h
    mov dx, [Player1Drawy]
    add [Player1Drawy], 1h 
    cmp dx, [Player1Drawy + 14h]
    jl DrawPlayer1Loop
    jg GoToCheckIfPlayer1Won

proc GoToCheckIfPlayer1Won
    call CheckIfPlayer1Won
    jmp CheckPlayer2Number
endp GoToCheckIfPlayer1Won

proc CheckPlayer2Number
    mov ah, 7
    int 21h
    cmp al, 31h
    je Player2CheckColumn1
    cmp al, 32h
    je Player2CheckColumn2
    cmp al, 33h
    je MoveToCheck2Column3
    cmp al, 34h
    je MoveToCheck2Column4
    jmp CheckPlayer2Number
endp CheckPlayer2Number

proc Player2CheckColumn1
    cmp [FirstColumnArray], 0
    je Change2Column1Number1 
    cmp [FirstColumnArray + 1], 0
    je Change2Column1Number2 
    cmp [FirstColumnArray + 2], 0
    je Change2Column1Number3 
    cmp [FirstColumnArray + 3], 0
    je Change2Column1Number4
    jmp CheckPlayer2Number
endp Player2CheckColumn1

proc Change2Column1Number1
    add [FirstColumnArray], 2
    mov [Player2Drawx], 25h
    mov [Player2Drawy], 85h
    jmp DrawPlayer2Disc
endp Change2Column1Number1

proc Change2Column1Number2
    add [FirstColumnArray + 1], 2
    mov [Player2Drawx], 25h
    mov [Player2Drawy], 67h
    jmp DrawPlayer2Disc
endp Change2Column1Number2

proc Change2Column1Number3
    add [FirstColumnArray + 2], 2
    mov [Player2Drawx], 25h
    mov [Player2Drawy], 47h
    jmp DrawPlayer2Disc
endp Change2Column1Number3

proc Change2Column1Number4
    add [FirstColumnArray + 3], 2
    mov [Player2Drawx], 25h
    mov [Player2Drawy], 27h
    jmp DrawPlayer2Disc
endp Change2Column1Number4

proc MoveToCheck2Column3
    jmp Player2CheckColumn3
endp MoveToCheck2Column3

proc MoveToCheck2Column4
    jmp Player2CheckColumn4
endp MoveToCheck2Column4    

proc Player2CheckColumn2
    cmp [SecondColumnArray], 0
    je Change2Column2Number1
    cmp [SecondColumnArray + 1], 0
    je Change2Column2Number2
    cmp [SecondColumnArray + 2], 0
    je Change2Column2Number3
    cmp [SecondColumnArray + 3], 0
    je Change2Column2Number4
    jmp CheckPlayer2Number
endp Player2CheckColumn2

proc Change2Column2Number1
    add [SecondColumnArray], 2
    mov [Player2Drawx], 45h
    mov [Player2Drawy], 85h
    jmp DrawPlayer2Disc
endp Change2Column2Number1

proc Change2Column2Number2
    add [SecondColumnArray + 1], 2
    mov [Player2Drawx], 45h
    mov [Player2Drawy], 67h
    jmp DrawPlayer2Disc
endp Change2Column2Number2

proc Change2Column2Number3
    add [SecondColumnArray + 2], 2
    mov [Player2Drawx], 45h
    mov [Player2Drawy], 47h
    jmp DrawPlayer2Disc
endp Change2Column2Number3

proc Change2Column2Number4
    add [SecondColumnArray + 3], 2
    mov [Player2Drawx], 45h
    mov [Player2Drawy], 47h
    jmp DrawPlayer2Disc
endp Change2Column2Number4

proc Player2CheckColumn3
    cmp [ThirdColumnArray], 0
    je Change2Column3Number1
    cmp [ThirdColumnArray + 1], 0
    je Change2Column3Number2
    cmp [ThirdColumnArray + 2], 0
    je Change2Column3Number3
    cmp [ThirdColumnArray + 3], 0
    je Change2Column3Number4
    jmp CheckPlayer2Number
endp Player2CheckColumn3

proc Change2Column3Number1
    add [ThirdColumnArray], 2
    mov [Player2Drawx], 65h
    mov [Player2Drawy], 85h
    jmp DrawPlayer2Disc
endp Change2Column3Number1

proc Change2Column3Number2
    add [ThirdColumnArray], 2
    mov [Player2Drawx], 65h
    mov [Player2Drawy], 67h
    jmp DrawPlayer2Disc
endp Change2Column3Number2

proc Change2Column3Number3
    add [ThirdColumnArray], 2
    mov [Player2Drawx], 65h
    mov [Player2Drawy], 47h
    jmp DrawPlayer2Disc
endp Change2Column3Number3

proc Change2Column3Number4
    add [ThirdColumnArray], 2
    mov [Player2Drawx], 65h
    mov [Player2Drawy], 27h
    jmp DrawPlayer2Disc
endp Change2Column3Number4

proc Player2CheckColumn4
    cmp [FourthColumnArray], 0
    je Change2Column4Number1
    cmp [FourthColumnArray + 1], 0
    je Change2Column4Number2
    cmp [FourthColumnArray + 2], 0
    je Change2Column4Number3
    cmp [FourthColumnArray + 3], 0
    je Change2Column4Number4
    jmp CheckPlayer2Number  
endp Player2CheckColumn4

proc Change2Column4Number1
    add [FourthColumnArray], 2
    mov [Player2Drawx], 85h
    mov [Player2Drawy], 85h
    jmp DrawPlayer2Disc
endp Change2Column4Number1

proc Change2Column4Number2
    add [FourthColumnArray], 2
    mov [Player2Drawx], 85h
    mov [Player2Drawy], 67h
    jmp DrawPlayer2Disc
endp Change2Column4Number2

proc Change2Column4Number3
    add [FourthColumnArray], 2
    mov [Player2Drawx], 85h
    mov [Player2Drawy], 47h
    jmp DrawPlayer2Disc
endp Change2Column4Number3

proc Change2Column4Number4
    add [FourthColumnArray], 2
    mov [Player2Drawx], 85h
    mov [Player2Drawy], 27h
    jmp DrawPlayer2Disc
endp Change2Column4Number4

DrawPlayer2Loop:
    mov bh,0h
    mov cx,[Player2Drawx]
    mov dx,[Player2Drawy]
    mov al,[player2disccolor]
    mov ah,0ch
    int 10h
    inc [Player2Drawx]
    cmp cx, [Player2Drawx + 14h]
    jl DrawPlayer2Loop

DrawPlayer2Disc: 
    mov bh, 0h
    inc [Player2Drawy]
    cmp dx, [Player2Drawy + 14h]
    jl DrawPlayer2Loop

proc GoToCheckIfPlayer2Won
    call CheckIfPlayer2Won
    jmp CheckPlayer1Number
endp GoToCheckIfPlayer2Won

next:
    ; Wait for key press
     mov ah,00h
     int 16h
    ; Return to text mode
    mov ah, 0
    mov al, 2
    int 10h

exit:
    mov ax, 4c00h
    int 21h
END start
```

I am making the game "Connect Four" (it's a very simple game, if you don't know about it a 2 min read of the game will do it). I have two problems with my code:

1 - The drawing part which is supposed to draw the discs (a square). Here's how it looks when you try to do so:
[image]

The problem happens in the drawing part (DrawPlayer1Loop and DrawPlayer1Disc, of course it also happens in Player2).

2 - The game is supposed to switch between the players but for some reason, it doesn't. When the player 1 turn finishes, it is supposed to jump to GoToCheckIfPlayer1Won. After that, it calls CheckPlayer1Won and checks if he won. If not, it jumps to CheckPlayer2Number which basically switches the turn to the second player, but it doesn't.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Seriously KatomPower, a cry for help? You can the most voted answer in this site, add a "Please answer ASAP" and that alone would make it off-topic. Learn an important lesson for when you'll be working: When you can't complete a project, focus on not making it a complete failure. Take the best of you code, isolate the missing features, explain the design choices and the difficulties you came across, document it. Out of pity: `cmp cx, [Player2Drawx + 14h]` is wrong, you'd need `[PlayerDrawx] + 14h` but thatmust be splitted. Debug! Debug! Debug! Don't waste your and our time.

Comment: @MargaretBloom Thank you for answering and really sorry that I am making this impression. First of all, I am kinda new to this site so I just wrote whatever comes to my mind. Second of all, I changed my code and it said "Illegal memory reference". And finally, do you have any idea why it doesn't change turns?

Answer (score 1):

Do compare these codes.
For the 1st player:

> ```
> DrawPlayer1Disc: 
>     mov bh, 0h
>     mov dx, [Player1Drawy]
>     add [Player1Drawy], 1h 
>     cmp dx, [Player1Drawy + 14h]
>     jl DrawPlayer1Loop
>     jg GoToCheckIfPlayer1Won
>     .
> proc GoToCheckIfPlayer1Won
> ```

For the 2nd player:

> ```
> DrawPlayer2Disc: 
>     mov bh, 0h
>     inc [Player2Drawy]
>     cmp dx, [Player2Drawy + 14h]
>     jl DrawPlayer2Loop
>     .
> proc GoToCheckIfPlayer2Won
> ```

These codes should closely resemble each other!

- In the 1st code the `jg GoToCheckIfPlayer1Won` is redundant. You want to fall through as soon as the shape is drawn.
- In the 2nd code you don't initialize the DX register before using it!

---

I suspect that everywhere that you wrote `[... + 14h] you think this number 14h is the actual size of the object. If this is the case then you cannot compare it the way you did.

```
mov dx, [Player1Drawy]
add [Player1Drawy], 1h 
mov ax, dx
add ax, 14h    ;This makes AX the position of the bottom side!
cmp dx, ax
jl DrawPlayer1Loop
```

---

To be able to switch users you need to actually return from the *CheckIfPlayer1Won* and *ChackIfPlayer2Won* procedures:

```
je Player1WinnerAnnounce3
jmp CheckIfPlayer2Won   <<<< Change into a RET instruction!
.
Player1WinnerAnnounce3:
```

also

```
je Player2WinnerAnnounce3
jmp CheckPlayer1Number <<<< Change into a RET instruction!

Player2WinnerAnnounce3:
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I changed it as you said but not it just draws it, covering the whole screen in yellow and making the program to crash. Why does it do that and do you know how to fix my second problem, that it doesn't switch turns?

Comment: Added solution to switch users.

Comment: Again, you don't understand how much you are helping me, thank you so much. The drawing part still doesn't work and I implemented your code.

Comment: I changed it to ret but it still doesn't work. Why doesn't it work?